# Spring expression language (SpEL) with jms selector

Tags: jms, spring-jms

We have a requirement to segregate the incoming messages based on environment property defined in the application properties. I have come up with following configuration but that is not working, any suggestion?

```
@JmsListener(id = "queueListener", destination = "${request.jms.queue}", containerFactory = "requestJmsListenerContainerFactory", selector = "ENV=${jms.env}")
public void onMessage(final Message message, MessageHeaders headers)
```

Every message has ENV property and "jms.env" application property can have value e.g. DEV, UAT etc. We are using Spring 4 and Websphere JMS

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: This listener is not working, I don't get any messages picked up by this listener..so I guess selector expression is not working here

Answer (score 0):

This started working after we changed selector expression to add quotes around value part i.e. "ENV='${jms.env}'"